# iPhone標準の音楽アプリのようなテーブルビューを作成したい。

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

iPhone標準の音楽アプリのような複数階層のテーブルビューを作成したいと思うのですが
1. `ViewController`を作成(名前は`ViewController`)し、その上に`TableView`を置く（アルバム一覧のページとします）
2. 同じものをもう一つ作成(名前は`nextViewController`)する（曲一覧のページとします）
3. 1で作成した`ViewController`を2で作成した`ViewController`と接続（セグエ）する
4. 最初のテーブル（アルバム一覧）に以下のようなコードを追加する

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var newVC = segue.sourceViewController as! nextViewController
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath　indexPath:NSIndexPath!) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("セグエ名",sender: nil)
}
```

これだけでは次の`View`へ移動することはできないのでしょうか？
`var newVC = segue.sourceViewController as! nextViewController`
この部分でCould not cast value of typeとエラー出力されます。

(`cellForRowAtIndexPath`や`numberOfRowsInSection`などのテーブル構成に必要なデータは入力し、正常に表示されていることを確認しました。)

何が足りないかご指導お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIStoryboardSegue`クラスのプロパティ`sourceViewController`は、遷移前の`ViewController`のことです。あなたは遷移後のものと勘違いなさっているのではありませんか？
遷移後の`ViewController`は、`destinationViewController`。

[UIStoryboardSegue Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIStoryboardSegue)

英語の勉強をするとき、英和辞典が手放せないのと同様に、iOSアプリの開発をするときは、かならずクラスリファレンスを読もう！

Comment: ご指摘の通り勘違いしておりました、お恥ずかしい限りです。
リファレンスの読み込みが足りず、申し訳ありません。

ご回答ありがとうございました。